# How to return a Mono using webTestClient in Spring WebFlux testing?

Tags: spring-webflux, junit-jupiter

I have a Rest service in Spring WebFlux that returns a `Mono<Person>` from a `/person/{id}` endpoint.

When I write my Junit test such as this it is expecting a Flux from the webTestClient as my code below shows:

```
Flux<Person> personFlux = webTestClient.get().uri("/persons/"+id)
                .exchange().expectStatus().isOk().returnResult(Person.class).getResponseBody();
```

The `returnResult` method is returning a `FluxExchangeResult<T>` which gives back a `Flux` type instead of a `Mono type I am expecting.

Is there a way to get `Mono` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the resulting `Flux` to `Mono`. There are two options depending on your use case: `single()` or `next()`

```java
Mono<Person> personMono = webTestClient.get().uri("/persons/" + id)
                .exchange().expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(Person.class)
                .getResponseBody()
                .single(); // or next()
```

`single()` operator picks the first element from the `Flux`. If zero or more than one element is emitted it will throw an error. On the other hand, `next()` operator is more lenient and allows the `Flux` to emit zero or more items. It just takes the first one and the rest are ignored.